# How to compare values from 3 files using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to compare three files with some common and unique values in them, I want to club all the three files in one file. I want to find the common values between all three files, second, all the values  which are atleast present in any two file third, the values which are unique to one file versus other two. I wrote a code for this but it is only giving me the common ones only.

I only want to make compare the "name" column between the file (Not all colum), however want to print all three columns from all three files

```
$ cat file_1    
id,name,value
1,a,20
2,b,34
3,c,5

$ cat file_2
id,name,value
1,a,27
2,b,55
7,d,15
9,z,100

$ cat file_3
id,name,value
1,a,77
2,b,95
11,d,83
6,y,109
```

Expected output:

```
id,name,value,id2,name2,value2,id3,name3,value3
1,a,20,1,a,27,1,a,77
2,b,34,2,b,55,2,b,95
3,c,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
NA,NA,NA,7,d,15,11,d,83
NA,NA,NA,9,z,100,NA,NA,NA
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,y,109
```

I tried this code but is is only giving me the comparision between two file. and not giving me the unique values

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ",";  
    print "id,name,value,id2,name2,value2,id3,name3,value3";  
}


function print_na_row(name) {
    print name, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA";
}

# Read file1.csv and store the data in an array
NR == FNR && FNR > 1 {
    id = $1;
    name = $2;
    value = $3;
    
    file1_data[name] = id "," value;
    next;
}

# Read file2.csv and file3.csv and merge with data from file1.csv
FNR > 1 {
    id = $1;
    name = $2;
    value = $3;
    
    current_row = id "," value;
    if (name in file1_data) {
        print name, file1_data[name], current_row;
        delete file1_data[name];  # Remove the matched entry to handle unique values in file1.csv
    } else {
        print_na_row(name);
    }
}
END {
    for (id in file1_data) {
        print_na_row(name);
    }
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. I have modified my  question.

Comment: all the files are comma delimited, this space is not there in the orginal files it came when i typed the question

Comment: since you need to compare rows across all 3 files I don't see how you can issue any `print` commands until *after* all 3 files have been completely processed, which means the `print` command(s) should reside in an `END{...}` block, which means storing all data in memory (prior to the `END{...}` block)

Comment: the problem with the command is it is only comaring 2 files.. and not the third file. Dont know how to do that

Comment: we can remove the first column its is anyway not important and use the "name".. I was writing with the mind set that I will just bring the entire fill together and later using cut i'll choose the columns i need.

Comment: It looks like you want something like `join -a1 file1 -a2 <( join -a1 file2 -a2 file3)` and of course you could replace `join` with your `myAwkJoin` in a similar fashion. Just and idea, and sorry, I don't have time right now to test this with your data. Good luck.

Comment: is the ordering of the output rows important?

Comment: what is your `awk` version (ie, what is the output from `awk --version`)?

Comment: no, the ordering is not important. the version is 5.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN  { FS = OFS = "," }
FNR==1 { fcnt++; next }
       { names[$2]; lines[$2 FS fcnt] = $0 }
END    { print "id,name,value,id2,name2,value2,id3,name3,value3"
         for (name in names) {
             out = sep = ""
             for (i=1; i<=fcnt; i++) {
                 out = out sep (lines[name FS i] ? lines[name FS i] : "NA,NA,NA")
                 sep = OFS
             }
             print out
         }
       }
' file_1 file_2 file_3
```

**NOTES:**

- per OP's comment we don't have to worry about ordering otherwise ...
- OP would need to specify the sorting criteria

This generates:

```
id,name,value,id2,name2,value2,id3,name3,value3
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,y,109
NA,NA,NA,9,z,100,NA,NA,NA
1,a,20,1,a,27,1,a,77
2,b,34,2,b,55,2,b,95
3,c,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
NA,NA,NA,7,d,15,11,d,83
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you'd want the expected output you show and I'm having a hard time believing you really would want such output so here's some output that makes sense to me (the usual output format expected from `join` operations with the common field first then the different fields per input file) and you can massage to suit.

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
    dfltRow = "NA" FS "NA"
}
FNR == 1 {
    ++numFiles
    $1 = $1 "_" numFiles
    $3 = $3 "_" numFiles
}
{
    if ( !seen[$2]++ ) {
        keys[++numKeys] = $2
    }
    rows[$2 FS numFiles] = $1 FS $3
}
END {
    for ( keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++ ) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%s", key
        for ( fileNr=1; fileNr<=numFiles; fileNr++ ) {
            idx = key FS fileNr
            row = ( idx in rows ? rows[idx] : dfltRow )
            numFlds = split(row,flds)
            for ( fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++ ) {
                printf "%s%s", OFS, flds[fldNr]
            }
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file_{1..3}
name,id_1,value_1,id_2,value_2,id_3,value_3
a,1,20,1,27,1,77
b,2,34,2,55,2,95
c,3,5,NA,NA,NA,NA
d,NA,NA,7,15,11,83
z,NA,NA,9,100,NA,NA
y,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,109
```

Answer (score 0):

> want to find the common values between all three files, second, all
> the values which are atleast present in any two file third, the values
> which are unique to one file versus other two

I suggest following approach: store counts of lines in 2D array where keys are line,filename consider following simple example
`file1.txt` content is

```
A
B
C
```

`file2.txt` content is

```
C
B
```

file3.txt content is

```
C
C
```

then

```
awk '{arr[$0][FILENAME]+=1}END{for(i in arr){print i,"is present in",length(arr[i]),"file(s)"}}' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

gives output

```
A is present in 1 file(s)
B is present in 2 file(s)
C is present in 3 file(s)
```

Explanation: for each line increase value in array `arr` under key current line content (`$0`), name of file by 1. When all files are processing `print` lines and in how many files they are present. Observe that this code does not count repeated line in `file3.txt` as if would be 2 files. This code should work properly with more than 3 files.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '
    FILENAME != file { fidx+=1; file=FILENAME }
    FNR == 1{
        for(i=1; i<=NF;i++) $i=$i fidx","
        header=header $0;
        next
    }
    !($1","1 in a){
        ids[$1]
        a[$1","1]=a[$1","2]=a[$1","3]="NA,NA,NA"
    }
    { a[$1","fidx]=$0 }
    END{
        gsub(/ |,$/,"",header)
        print header
        for (id in ids){
            out=""
            for(i=1; i<=3; i++){
                out=out sprintf("%s,",a[id","i])
            }
            sub(/,$/,"",out)
            print out
        }
    }
'  input_file[1-3]

id1,name1,value1,id2,name2,value2,id3,name3,value3
1,a,20,1,a,27,1,a,77
2,b,34,2,b,55,2,b,95
3,c,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,y,109
NA,NA,NA,7,d,15,NA,NA,NA
NA,NA,NA,9,z,100,NA,NA,NA
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,11,d,83
```